# Python auto re-launch script

Tags: python, crash, relaunch

My OS is OSX Maverick
Python 3.x

I have a python script sample.py that I run in terminal.
Sometime due to unexplained reason my script crash.
Is there a way to re-launch my script automatically on crash?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It might be a better idea to prevent the script from crashing. In that case, source code would help.

Comment: The crash are due to some external error the script is not faulty

Comment: @user3224813 Then you should build your script to handle those external errors.  Look into [```try...except```](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) as a way to handle exceptions